# Does Healing Trees Benefit Me in Any Way?

Tags: caster

If you shoot the petrified trees around the area, they'll burst forth with new life and the leaves will turn a vibrant green.  But aside from the mission(s) where your goal is to heal trees, does healing trees give you anything useful (aside from pretty scenery)?

[image: The tree, it is dead.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blasting trees will improve your score and give you money to purchase upgrades. It's not a big bonus, though, you'll only get 10 points per tree. The easiest enemy gives 500.